# Show that the system $\gamma $ of all countable subsets of the set $X$ is a σ-algebra if and only if $X$ is countable.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the system $\gamma $ of all countable subsets of the set $X$
>   is a σ-algebra if and only if $X$ is countable.

Can someone help me, how to prove it? I started learning σ-algebra, but I am lost.

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under taking complements.

Comment: Brian M. Scott's argument gives you one direction, and the other one follows immediately using the fact that the power set of any set is a $\sigma$-algebra on it.

Comment: @MarkusZetto why the power set of any set is a σ-algebra on it? Can you explain it, please?

Comment: @Peter Well, it is closed under arbitrary unions and complements, and includes the set itself and $\emptyset$.

Comment: @MarkusZetto thank you